# Determine original purchase date of an Android application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is it possible to use the Android in-app billing API to determine the original purchase date of the application?  It looks like making a `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS` request may provide that information, but I can't tell from any of the documentation.